# button of javascript is displaying but function is not working

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to call a function in javascript by clicking a button but the problem is that when I used to click the button then it do nothing i.e it doesn't call the function...

The following is the code

```
 <?php

function view_cat1()
 {
$i=1;
include("inc/db.php");
$fetch_data=$con->prepare("select * from main_cat order by cat_name");
$fetch_data->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$fetch_data->execute();

while($row=$fetch_data->fetch())
{

    echo"<tr><td>".$i++."</td>

           <td>".$row['cat_id']."</td>
           <td>".$row['cat_name']."</td>
           <td><a href='index.php?edit_cat=".$row['cat_id']."'>Edit</td>

         <td><input type='button' onclick='delete_category(<?php echo 
   ".$row['cat_id'].")' name='delete' value='Delete'></td>

    </tr> ";

}




}   

?>   


<script language="javascript'">;
 function delete_category(delname)
        {
    if(confirm("are you sure"))
    {
        window.location.href='delete_cat.php?del_name='+delname+'';
        return true;
    }

</script>
<?php
```

The above code don't use to show the confirmation message .

Comment: Could you give us the HTML rendered on your page?

Comment: check proper syntax

Comment: Check console for errors.

Comment: you have a typo here `<script language="javascript'">;` (a single quote)

Answer (score 1):

Modify the JavaScript as below, it may works:

```
<script>
 function delete_category(delname)
    {
        if(confirm("are you sure"))
        {
            window.location.href='delete_cat.php?del_name='+delname+'';
            return true;
        }
    }    
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `language` attribute has been deprecated for a long time, and should not be used. Also, you missed the closing brace `}` of the `delete_category` function.

```
<script>
    function delete_category(delname) {
        if (confirm("are you sure")) {
            window.location.href = 'delete_cat.php?del_name=' + delname + '';
            return true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

You can use the attribute `type="text/javascript"` if you are **not** using `HTML5`

Answer (score 0):

To simplify your code and make fewer mistakes, you could use a single `echo` statement in your `while` loop. If you render HTML with JavaScript functions linked with events, don't forget to add quotation marks around the arguments of the function. In your case, the function `delete_category` takes in as argument `$row['cat_id']`. To do that escape the double quotes with a blackslash : `\"`

Here is an example:

```
<?php

$var = "hello";
echo "<input type='button' onclick='delete_category(\"".$var."\")' name='delete' value='Delete'>";
```